# have button call a specfic excel filename?

Tags: ms-access, vba

```html
Private Sub Excel_File_Click()
Dim stAppName As String
Dim Nozero As String
Nozero = VAL(strFFF)
stAppName = "excel.exe C:\Users\excel\xxx " & Nozero & ".xlsx"
Call Shell(stAppName, 1)
End Sub
```

have an ms access form by case number and need to add a button to pull up the excel file with the case number, but the case number has (leading)zero's, strip the zero's and pull the file with correct characters in xxx(space)111.xlsx. 
excel file: xxx 111.xlsx
case number(7 characters): xxxxxxx
table: tblCase
column: fff
please help
thank you

Fixed it and posting for others to use

```
Private Sub Excel_File_Click()
Dim Nozero As String
Nozero = Nz(strFFF)
//test variable to ensure correct path and file name
MsgBox "C:\Users\excel\xxx " & Nozero & ".xlsx"
Dim objXLApp As Object
    Dim objXLBook As Object
    Set objXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objXLBook = objXLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\excel\xxx " & Nozero & ".xlsx")
objXLApp.Application.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Val() function will drop the leading zeros. Also, an empty string will return as 0.

Comment: Thanks, changed it to Val bit still not working. StrFFF is a cell in table and form, it doesnt seem to grab the data even though I use the same word. It should pick up from the current form, the case number

Comment: @June7 Correction, got it to pick up the case number, but VAL () did not get rid of the leading 0's, also it seems to check the desktop directory as well.

Comment: You say the case number is 7 digits so it should work and it does for me. Edit question to show revised code and new info.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, changed

Comment: Don't see anything changed.

Comment: Private Sub Excel_File_Click()
Dim Nozero As String
Nozero = Nz(strFFF)
//test variable to ensure correct path and file name
MsgBox "C:\Users\excel\xxx " & Nozero & ".xlsx"
Dim objXLApp As Object
    Dim objXLBook As Object
    Set objXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objXLBook = objXLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\excel\xxx " & Nozero & ".xlsx")
objXLApp.Application.Visible = True
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it and posting for others to use, just add that to a button in a form or report and call it by setting it in the button properties. Changed the characters to integers in the DB. enjoy

```
Private Sub Excel_File_Click()
Dim Nozero As String
Nozero = Nz(strFFF)
//test variable to ensure correct path and file name
MsgBox "C:\Users\excel\xxx " & Nozero & ".xlsx"
Dim objXLApp As Object
    Dim objXLBook As Object
    Set objXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objXLBook = objXLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\excel\xxx " & Nozero & ".xlsx")
objXLApp.Application.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Going back to my orginal question about removing leading 0's in an alphanumeric value, do this OldStr = "0000012345"
NewStr = Trim(Val(OldStr))